VLOOKUP or similar to find value from Col C when range of numbers is in Cols A and B
My lookup data is as follows:
       ColA   ColB   ColC
Row1   Low    High   Adjusted value
Row2   0.5    1.4    1
Row3   1.5    2.3    2
Row4   2.4    3.2    3
Row5   3.3    4.2    4
Row6   4.3    5.1    5
Row7   5.2    6.1    6
Row8   6.2    7.0    7
Row9   7.1    8.0    8

If I have a cell containing a value of 0.9 or 1.2 then I want a formula to return 1. If I have a value of 7.3 I want to see 8, etc. In line with the data above.
In Google Sheets, how do I look this up?


You may try:
=ifna(filter(C:C,map(A:A,B:B,lambda(a,b,isbetween(E1,a,b)))),"--")



Perfect - thank you!
